# .clearqueue() does not stop animation

Tags: jquery

```
<button id="clear">clearqueue</button>
<span id="1" style="background-color:yellow; width:100px">I am script 1</span><br />
<span id="2" style="background-color:pink; width:100px">I am script 2</span>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$( 'span#1' ).animate({'width': '300px'},1000)
.queue(function(){$( 'span#2' ).animate({'width': '300px'},1000);
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#clear').click(function(){$('span#1').clearqueue();});
</script>
```

I am trying to stop the animation after clicking on the button and it does not work. Hoping to get help from another pair of eyes.

Comment: its clearQueue with a capital Q and it is working as it is supposed to. Also, you don't need two script tags, combine everything into one like this http://jsbin.com/xozafi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

clearQueue() is in camelCase try writing ,

```
$('#clear').click(function(){$('span#1').clearQueue()});
```

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/9hpc3x3o/1/)

clearQueue() will not stop the animation which is running currently, for that you need stop() instead of clearQueue() it works,

```
$('#clear').click(function(){$('span#1').stop(true);});
```

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/9hpc3x3o/)

Make sure to write `true` within the `stop()` which indicates that all the animations should be stopped.